# How to get true if all the array elements in the same position are true

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, boolean

I'm working with n boolean arrays like the following ones:

```
A  = [1, 1, 0, 1]
A1 = [0, 1, 0, 1]
A2 = [0, 1, 0, 0]

B  = [1, 1, 0, 1]
B1 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
B2 = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I'm working on a function that return true if exists at least one *column* of 1 (e.g. in the three A arrays I'll got true because `A[1] = A1[1] = A2[1] = true`)
In the B arrays I'll get false instead.

I know that I can make a result boolean array and obtain the output with loops but I'm asking if there is a more elegant way to obtain this result without using too many loops.

Comment: all array have same length? column can be any?

Comment: Maybe you could convert the array into a binary representation and then perform a AND operation and check if result is 0 or not! But I don't think this is any better than your approach!

Comment: @Grundy columns must be the same length and only boolean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
bool[] A = ...;
bool[] A1 = ...;
bool[] A2 = ...;

var length = Math.Min(Math.Min(A.Length, A1.Length), A2.Length);
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, length).Any(i => A[i] && A1[i] && A2[i]);
```

You can skip the length calculation if you know in advance what the length is, that will take a line off.

Answer (score 1):

The following allows you specify as many arrays as you wish

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var A = new bool[] { true, true, false, true };
            var A1 = new bool[] { false, true, false, true };
            var A2 = new bool[] { false, true, false, false };

            var B = new bool[] { true, true, false, true };
            var B1 = new bool[] { false, false, false, true };
            var B2 = new bool[] { false, true, false, false };

            Console.WriteLine(AtLeastOneColumnIsTrue(A, A1, A2));
            Console.WriteLine(AtLeastOneColumnIsTrue(B, B1, B2));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool AtLeastOneColumnIsTrue(params bool[][] boolArrays)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < boolArrays[0].Length; column++)
            {
                var columnIsAllTrue = true;

                for (int boolArray = 0; boolArray < boolArrays.Length && columnIsAllTrue; boolArray++)
                {
                    columnIsAllTrue = columnIsAllTrue && boolArrays[boolArray][column];
                }

                if (columnIsAllTrue)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, approach not depends on number of arrays:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool[] Convert(params bool[][] args)
    {            
        return (new List<bool[]>(args)).Aggregate((a, b) => a.Select((x, i) => x && b[i]).ToArray());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new[] { true, true, false, true };
        var A1 = new[] { false, true, false, true };
        var A2 = new[] { false, true, false, false };
        var A3 = new[] { true, true, true, true };

        var res = Convert(A, A1, A2, A3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195760/284240) since this uses `boolean[][]`:

Your sample arrays:

```
bool[][] boolArrays1 = { 
                           new[]{true, true, false, true}, 
                           new[]{false, true, false, true}, 
                           new[]{false, true, false, false}, 
                       };
bool[][] boolArrays2 = { 
                           new[]{true, true, false, true}, 
                           new[]{false, false, false, true}, 
                           new[]{false, true, false, false}, 
                       };
```

Now you can use a combination of `Any` and `All`:

```
bool anyColumnTrue1 = Enumerable.Range(0, boolArrays1.Min(arr => arr.Length))
    .Any(ix => boolArrays1.All(arr => arr[ix]));  // true
bool anyColumnTrue2 = Enumerable.Range(0, boolArrays2.Min(arr => arr.Length))
    .Any(ix => boolArrays2.All(arr => arr[ix]));  // false
```

Since you have asked for a method, you could use this extension method which supports arrays and lists which can be stored in any kind of sequence:

```
public static bool AnyColumnTrue(this IEnumerable<IList<bool>> bools) 
{
    if (bools == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bools");

    return Enumerable.Range(0, bools.Min(seq => seq.Count))
        .Any(ix => bools.All(arr => arr[ix]));
}
```

Then it's simple and readable:

```
bool anyColumnTrue = boolArrays1.AnyColumnTrue();
```

---

If you actually have array variables and not a collection you can still use my method easily:

```
bool anyColumnTrue = new[]{ A, A1, A2 }.AnyColumnTrue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an *extracted method* for this (and where you can put arbitrary number of arrays of arbitrary lengths):

```
    private static Boolean HasOnes(params Boolean[][] items) {
      for (int i = items.Min(line => line.Length) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        if (items.All(line => line[i]))
          return true;

      return false;
    }

....

    Boolean[] A =  { true, true, false, true };
    Boolean[] A1 = { false, true, true, true };
    Boolean[] A2 = { false, true, false, false };

    Console.Write(HasOnes(A, A1, A2) ? "Yes" : "No");

    Boolean[] B  = {true, true, false, true};
    Boolean[] B1 = {false false, false, true};
    Boolean[] B2 = {false, true, false, false};

    Console.Write(HasOnes(B, B1, B2) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using Linq:

```
var anyColumnAllTrue = A.Select((value, index) => 
    value && A1[index] && A2[index])
.Any(result => result);
```

Answer (score 0):

While this conversion process is far from the fastest, I would prefer to look at this situation as a set of binary bits, rather than a sequence of bools - at which point a binary AND will give you the answer:

```
int ToInt(IEnumerable<bool> bits) => bits.Select((b, i) => ((b ? 1 : 0) << i))
                                         .Aggregate((b, b1) => (b | b1));    

bool HasCommonBits(params <IEnumerable<bool>[] seqs) => 
     seqs.Aggregate((s, i) => s.ToInt() & i) > 0;
...

if(HasCommonBits(A, A1, A2))
...
```